# I can't install showbox apk into Huawei P10

Tags: installation, apk

I installed showbox apk to my xiaomi phone it works well.
But, when i install it to my other android phone (huawei p10)
it just get stuck near at the end.

i have enabled install from unknown sources as well. help.

Link: https://showbox.guide/download-apk/

Comment: I guess you updated your Huawei device (Android 9) and Showbox doesn't compatible with this version of android.

Comment: My huawei is android 8.0.0 and is compatible. is just stuck at installing forever

Comment: anybody knows how to fix this issue???